# Slide element on diagonal at specific angle

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

My goal is to slide an element from right to left on diagonal at a specific angle no matter what the width or height of the device. Currently my code does it only from a specific location top right to specific location bottom left. What I'm looking for is to only give it the initial top right value and the angle and it should calculate bottom left by using the initial value plus the angle. This way the angle of the sliding effect will equal the angle of my element making it look good on any devices no matter the viewport width or height.

**html**

```
<a id="flymeby" href="#">Fly me by</a>
```

**js**

```
$( "#flymeby" ).click(function(e) {
$('body').append('<div class="flyby"></div>');
var left = $('.flyby').offset().left;
  e.preventDefault();
                $(".flyby").css({left:left}).animate({"left":"-500px", "top":"300px"}, 6600, "swing", function() {

                    $('.flyby').remove();
                });
});
```

**css**

```
body {
  overflow-x:hidden;
}
.flyby {
  width:500px;
  background:#000;
  width: 500px;
  height: 69px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50px;
  right: -500px;
  -webkit-transform-origin: top right;
  -ms-transform-origin: top right;
  transform-origin: top right;
  -webkit-transform: skewY(-15deg);
  -ms-transform: skewY(-15deg);
  transform: skewY(-15deg);
}
#flymeby {
  background:red;
  color:#fff;
  display:inline-block;
  padding:10px 20px;
}
```

**My work so far**
http://jsfiddle.net/fbtv5kpz/4/

**Update:** **Ideally I'd like the slide to be given no initial value just the angle and it should automatically slide in the middle of the screen from right to left.**
[image: Demo img for animation]

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with `animation` and [`translate()`](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_2dtransforms.asp)

Add class with the animation `onclick` the DOM `a`

[Working fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/u0pjc3zv/)

```js
$("#flymeby").click(function(e) {
  $(".flyby").addClass('startFly');
});
```

```css
body {
  overflow-x: hidden;
}

.flyby {
  width: 500px;
  background: #000;
  width: 500px;
  height: 69px;
  position: absolute;
  transform-origin: top right;
  transform: skewY(-15deg) translate(200%);
}

#flymeby {
  background: red;
  color: #fff;
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 10px 20px;
}

.startFly{
  animation: fly 6s linear;
}

@keyframes fly {
  100% {
 transform: skewY(-15deg) translate(-200%);
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a id="flymeby" href="#">Fly me by</a>
<div class="flyby"></div>
```

**UPDATE AS THE IMAGE YOU ATTACH**

```js
  var w=$(window).width();
  var h=$(window).height();
  var g=h+w;
  $(".flyby").css('transform','skewY(-15deg) translateX(' + g + 'px) translateY(' + 0 + 'px)' );

$("#flymeby").click(function(e) {
  $(".flyby").addClass('startFly');
});
```

```css
body {
  overflow-x: hidden;
  height: 100%;
}

html { height: 100%; }


.flyby {
  background: #000;
  width: 100px;
  height: 69px;
  position: absolute;
  transform-origin: top right;
}

#flymeby {
  background: red;
  color: #fff;
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 10px 20px;
}

.startFly{
  animation: fly 6s linear;
}

@keyframes fly {
  100% {
 transform: skewY(-15deg) translateY(80vh) translateX(0);
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a id="flymeby" href="#">Fly me by</a>
<div class="flyby"></div>
```

Comment: that what you mean?

Comment: In your example changing the width of viewport will make the element change initial position. I want to keep the same initial position. Ideally I would like the slide on diagonal in the middle of the screen at a 15deg angle.

Comment: Now the position of the element changes when the height of viewport changes.